# UIPickerview wont populate from a specific array based on value of different uitextfield

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, interface-builder

I have a textfield that is setting its value from a pickerview based on truck makes like ford, peterbilt, etc. That is working properly but I am trying to populate the correct array based on that value for the next textfield and its not populating anything.

I have tried doing that in the pickerview functions below:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 {

        return yearArray.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {

        return truckMakeArray.count
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {

        if truckMake.text == "Ford"{

            return fordModelArray.count}
```

and

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 {

        return yearArray[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {

        return truckMakeArray[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2{

        if truckMake.text == "Ford"{

            return fordModelArray[row]
        }
```

and

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    if pickerView.tag == 0 {

        truckYear.text = yearArray[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 1 {

        truckMake.text = truckMakeArray[row]
    } else if pickerView.tag == 2 {

        if truckMake.text == "Ford"{

            truckModel.text = fordModelArray[row]
        }
```

The problem is I have placed println()'s inside those statements where its comparing the truckMake.text and it skips right over it.

So the other way I tried was doing it in the following:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.tag == 5 {
        yearPicker.hidden = false
        truckMakePicker.hidden = true
        truckModelPicker.hidden = true

        pickerView.hidden = false
        self.pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.view.frame.size.height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)

        return false
    } else if textField.tag == 6 {
        yearPicker.hidden = true
        truckMakePicker.hidden = false
        truckModelPicker.hidden = true

        pickerView.hidden = false
        self.pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.view.frame.size.height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)

        return false
    } else if textField.tag == 7 {

        if truckMake.text == "Mack"{

            println("text method")

            modelArray = mackModelArray
        }

        yearPicker.hidden = true
        truckMakePicker.hidden = true
        truckModelPicker.hidden = false

        pickerView.hidden = false
        self.pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.view.frame.size.height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)

        return false
    } else {

        return true
    }
}
```

The logic behind this is that I created an empty array of type String and I am setting the array to the correct one based on that value only its not setting it. This time however I do get that println() inside to print "text method".

I have triple checked the tag numbers on the pickerviews and textfields, the delegates are all set for both and datasource for pickerviews.

Maybe someone can enlighten me on how to change the models based on the makes of the trucks.

Comment: @Nick89 would you have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Please do not use tags to distinguish your objects.

Comment: Im really new to swift, whats a better way to do so as they are all textfields or pickerviews.

Comment: Keep a property / variable to them to identify them.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to accomplish that? Or do you want me to make another question and tag you in it?

Comment: Is there  a way I can only use one pickerview and reuse it? That would be ideal but Im not back end a lot of the time so my brain doesn't know how to accomplish that.

Comment: Just create properties in your object for them and assign those when creating the pickers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, those pickerview functions only get called on load so if you do any comparing you must reload the pickerview components. Here's what I did:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    if textField.tag == 5 {
        yearPicker.hidden = false
        truckMakePicker.hidden = true
        truckModelPicker.hidden = true

        pickerView.hidden = false
        self.pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.view.frame.size.height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)

        return false
    } else if textField.tag == 6 {
        yearPicker.hidden = true
        truckMakePicker.hidden = false
        truckModelPicker.hidden = true

        pickerView.hidden = false
        self.pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.view.frame.size.height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)

        return false
    } else if textField.tag == 7 {

        yearPicker.hidden = true
        truckMakePicker.hidden = true
        truckModelPicker.hidden = false

        truckModelPicker.reloadAllComponents()

        pickerView.hidden = false
        self.pickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: scrollView.contentOffset.y + self.view.frame.size.height - 250, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 250)

        return false
    } else {

        return true
    }
}
```

the textField.tag == 7 is where I reload the data for that picker when the textfield is touched. Makes sense now, the only way I realized it was when the pickerview functions didnt call themselves again.